# Elapsed time without considering weekends and bank holidays in Java

Tags: java, date, time, stopwatch, elapsed

I've implemented a stopwatch that works fine without considering that bank holidays and weekends shouldn't be counted in the total duration. I was looking for some open-source library where I could get the elapsed time, passing a start instant, end instant and a set of bank holidays (weekends aren't counted in). The only library that makes me things easier is net.sf.jtemporal, but I have still to amplify the functionality.
Could anyone tell me if there is some useful library to get the wanted functionality?

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80541/given-two-dates-what-is-the-best-way-of-finding-the-number-of-weekdays-in-php#80627), probably the best and easiest approach is to create a table containing information about each day (work day count from beginning / bank holiday, etc; one row per day = 365 rows per year) and then just use count function / with proper selection.

Comment: Sorry I've edited my question specifying that the language that I use is Java. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can find something that specific.  But it's easy enough to create your own logic.  Here's some pseudocode...

```
private long CalculateTimeSpan(DateTime BeginDate, DateTime EndDate, ArrayList<DateTime> BankHollidays)
{
    long ticks = 0;
    while (BeginDate <= EndDate) // iterate until reaching end
    {
        if ((BeginDate is holliday?) || (BeginDate is Weekend?))
             skip;
        else
             ticks += (24*60*60*1000);

        BeginDate = BeginDate + 1 day; // add one day and iterate
    }

    return ticks;
}
```

Comment: I would use a HashSet to avoid putting values repeated, but it seems to me a little inefficient, specially because if the granularity is of seconds you have to iterate 60x60x24 times for each day. Any other more efficient idea for that case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you only count Bank Hours too?  9AM - 3PM?  Or is it 24 hours a day?

Comment: It's 24 hours a day. I got the elapsed timer but I want to return that duration subtracting the duration of the weekends and bank holidays within that interval.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  It is a much better date/time API than the one included with Java

Comment: Thanks but I've already done that, and it's better than Java's one but anyway I found net.sf.jtemporal fitter for my goal. As usingCompactPeriodStorage.periodIterator(Period period), you can get CloseableIterator that Iterates over all the periods of the storage that intersects the given period.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a valid solution to what your are looking for. It calculates the elapsed time (considering that one working day has 24 hours) without count the bank holidays and weekends in:

```
/**
 * Calculate elapsed time in milliseconds
 * 
 * @param startTime
 * @param endTime
 * @return elapsed time in milliseconds
 */

protected long calculateElapsedTimeAux(long startTime, long endTime) { 
    CustomizedGregorianCalendar calStartTime = new CustomizedGregorianCalendar(this.getTimeZone());
    CustomizedGregorianCalendar calEndTime = new CustomizedGregorianCalendar(this.getTimeZone());
    calStartTime.setTimeInMillis(startTime);
    calEndTime.setTimeInMillis(endTime);
    long ticks = 0;

    while (calStartTime.before(calEndTime)) { // iterate until reaching end 
        ticks = ticks + increaseElapsedTime(calStartTime, calEndTime);
    }

    return ticks;
}

private long increaseElapsedTime(CustomizedGregorianCalendar calStartTime, CustomizedGregorianCalendar calEndTime) {
    long interval;
    long ticks = 0;

    interval = HOURS_PER_DAY*MINUTES_PER_HOUR*SECONDS_PER_MIN*MILLISECONDS_PER_SEC; // Interval of one day

    if ( calEndTime.getTimeInMillis() - calStartTime.getTimeInMillis() < interval) {
        interval = calEndTime.getTimeInMillis() - calStartTime.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    ticks = increaseElapsedTimeAux(calStartTime, calEndTime, interval);
    calStartTime.setTimeInMillis(calStartTime.getTimeInMillis() + interval);

    return ticks;
}

protected long increaseElapsedTimeAux(CustomizedGregorianCalendar calStartTime, CustomizedGregorianCalendar calEndTime, long interval) {
    long ticks = 0;

    CustomizedGregorianCalendar calNextStartTime = new CustomizedGregorianCalendar(this.getTimeZone());
    calNextStartTime.setTimeInMillis(calStartTime.getTimeInMillis() + interval);

    if ( (calStartTime.isWorkingDay(_nonWorkingDays) && calNextStartTime.isWorkingDay(_nonWorkingDays)) ) { // calStartTime and calNextStartTime are working days
        ticks = interval;

    }
    else {
        if (calStartTime.isWorkingDay(_nonWorkingDays)) { // calStartTime is a working day and calNextStartTime is a non-working day
            ticks = (calStartTime.getNextDay().getTimeInMillis() - calStartTime.getTimeInMillis());
        }
        else {
            if (calNextStartTime.isWorkingDay(_nonWorkingDays)) { // calStartTime is a non-working day and calNextStartTime is a working day
                ticks = (calNextStartTime.getTimeInMillis() - calStartTime.getNextDay().getTimeInMillis());
            }
            else {} // calStartTime and calEndTime are non-working days
        }
    }

    return ticks;
}
```