# get all weekdays in php

Tags: php, date

I am thingking if how to get all the `date` of weekdays between a given `date`

example: I have a `date` given `2013-01-01` and `2013-20-01`

It must return all date of weekdays like `2013-01-01`

how could this be done using php
thankz

Comment: must have been asked before...surely?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352712/get-date-range-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80541/given-two-dates-what-is-the-best-way-of-finding-the-number-of-weekdays-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/dateperiod) Class, this is available from PHP 5.3.

Here is an example from the site

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2012-08-31' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){

       // You can manipulate the date here
    echo $date->format("Ymd") . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weekday from the timestamp using the multitude of formatting options avalaible:

```
echo date("D",strtotime("2013-01-01"));
```

tues